# How to choose the method visible method of a library

Tags: java, methods

I have created a library and I want to restrict the visibility of some methods. These methods are declared public because they are used all over the library (on diffrent packages). How can I do that ?

Example :

```
    public class X{
       public void A();
       public void B();
   }
```

I just want the method A to be visible through the app that integrates the library and not the method B.

Thanks !

Comment: logically, method A will only be visible to those who integrate your library... its already they way how you want it to be

Comment: i think he doesnt want B to show up as well. how about making b protexted?

Comment: The problem is that B is used in different package of my lib. Can ProGaurd can be a help for this problem or is there an easier way ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the method B() to be public in your library, then you cannot hide it to someone who uses the library.

You could separate the class X into an interface and an implementation, and only expose the interface to the users of your library:

```
public interface X {
    public void A();
}

public class XImpl implements X {
    @Override
    public void A() {...}

    public void B() {...}
}
```

This works if the library can be changed to use XImpl internally, so you can still use the B() method without casting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove access modifier from your method B and make it available within its package only.

```
public class X{
    public void A();
    void B();
}
```

or mark it as protected so its available within the sub-classes too.

```
public class X{
    public void A();
    protected void B();
}
```

For more info, read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).